# Link YouTube video in Product Image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I am having an issue placing a YouTube video in my Product Image Gallery. Currently, I have a large photo as the main product photo and thumbnails change the main product photo. An example is on my website [here](http://firesuppressiontech.com/heated-sample-lines/). When I try to place a video in the code below, I get a broken image link.

I'd like for the YouTube video to play when the thumbnail is selected. If I could get some assistance with this, that would be great. Being new to coding has limited my ability in solving this problem.

Right now, this is a pure HTML solution and the code is below. I am open to javascript though if that is easier.

I appreciate any and all help with this! Thank you

**HTML Main Product Photo**

```
<div class="image"><img name="preview" src="http://firesuppressiontech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/hsl7.jpg" alt=""/></div>
```

**Thumbnails**

```
<div class="thumbnails">
<img onclick="preview.src=img1.src" name="img1" src="http://firesuppressiontech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/hsl7.jpg" alt="" /><img onclick="preview.src=img2.src" name="img2" src="http://firesuppressiontech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/end.jpg" alt="" /><img onclick="preview.src=img3.src" name="img3" src="http://firesuppressiontech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/lhsl.png" alt="" /><img onclick="preview.src=img4.src" name="img4" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTiEz5j48x4" alt="" />
```

Comment: This wont work, because an image tag <img> can not play any kind of video. To solve this you want to use a video tag, or better an embedded youtube player.

Comment: @hyde Thanks for the help! I tried the video tag and it just places a black box on the thumbnail area. Is there a way to click the video thumbnail and have the video appear where the main product photo is at? I apologize for the minimal coding ability.

Comment: i will write you a small jQuery approach to get you in the right direction, coming soon

Comment: @hyde Many thanks! I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here you are: [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tk3ucvcd/2/)

```
(function ($, w) {
    w.contentToggle = {
        addVideo: function (videoId) {
            $('.image').html('<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoId +'?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');       
        },
        addImage: function (imageSrc) {
            $('.image').html('<img name="preview" src="' + imageSrc + '" alt=""/>');
        }
    };  
})(jQuery, window)
```

It is just a small script which changes the html content of .image on click of the thumbnails. Because jQuery is already included to your website I used it. Of course you can do things like this with pure JS (vanilla).
Hope you got the basic concept of switching contents with jQuery.

With this js snippet you have a new object (contentToggle) available at the global scope. This object contains two functions addVideo() and addImage().

Have fun improving this approach.

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you so much! And great touch as I am a big MSU fan :) I really appreciate the help with all of this.

Comment: no problem, as you can see I dropped some keywords so if you like to learn more about js and jQuery you should have a point to start from

Comment: I noticed that, this works great! Thank you again! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting a video link in a `<img>` tag, so it's the reason why doesn't work.

A solution could be insert it in a iframe as:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k?autoplay=1">
</iframe>
```

I hope it's helps.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be because of SSL/TLS certification or Copyright issues. Every video on web have a embed code. You have to copy that and paste in your main 'div'.
like I have a embed code for a video:

```
<iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3R1ysTlxiVY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

now cut the this specific part,

```
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3R1ysTlxiVY"
```

and copy to your desired container. Now, this is will not be contained into specific area as it is given any height-width, so you have to set width-height for that. You can attach the whole iframe in that case. if you don't allow full screen just set

```
allowfullscreen="0"
```

I hope this might work for you.